# How to create screen sharing application C#

Tags: c#, ip, port, screensharing

I have recently tried to make a screen sharing application, but it does not work. It works to share my own screen for myself, but not with my friend. Does the other user need to be connected to the same internet? I would really appreciate some help! :)

Comment: Refer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295309/simple-c-sharp-screen-sharing-application

Comment: Voting to close as too broad: _"There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't give much details about your problem, i am not even sure you have a problem. But the login behind a screensharing application, for me, is like this :

You have 2 clients (computers) connected to the internet, you'll have to connect them to each other (udp, tcp or even with a server if you want).

So Computer1 connects to Computer2 anv vice versa
Now if Computer1 is the one sharing his screen, you'll have to send to Computer2 the images every, lets say, 100ms.
Computer2 receives the images and display them over the time, it'll look like you're screensharing.

The main think here is :
- Connection between the two computers
- Sending & received data (images of the screen)

Comment: Ok, thanks! Now i understand.. :)